# Type of expression is ambiguous using Square code

Tags: swift3, square-connect

I am getting the following error message using the suggested Square Code for POS SDK "card present transactions" for Swift 3:

> T ype of expression is ambiguous without more context

The offending line of code is:

```
let apiRequest = try SCCAPIRequest(
```

I believe I have followed all the preparation steps properly such as registering URLs with Square and adding entries to AppDelegate.

The Square Code is:

```
do {
// Specify the amount of money to charge
 let money = try SCCMoney(amountCents: 100, currencyCode: "AUD")

// Create the request.
let apiRequest =
    try SCCAPIRequest(
        callbackURL: callbackURL,
        amount: money,
        userInfoString: nil,
        merchantID: locationId,
        notes:  note,
        customerID: nil,
        supportedTenderTypes: .cash, .card,
        clearsDefaultFees: false,
        returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: false
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`supportedTenderTypes` is an `NS_OPTIONS` enumeration. If you are planning to suppport multiple tender types, you need to **enclose them by square brackets**, like the following:

```
supportedTenderTypes: [.cash, .card]
```